# Real and Imaginary Parts of $\frac{\cos(z)}{(1-e^{ix})}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Find

$$\mathrm{Re}\bigg(\frac{\cos(x+iy)}{(1-e^{ix})}\bigg)$$

and

$$\mathrm{Im}\bigg(\frac{\cos(x+iy)}{(1-e^{ix})}\bigg)$$

Please help I've been trying for some time now...

Comment: two things: first please learn to use Latex. I've fixed the post for you but its a lot neater to read when it's pretty. ;) second. can you show us what you've tried so far? maybe that will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $1-e^{-ix}$ and you get a denominator that is real. Then you just have to find the real and imaginary parts of $\cos(x+iy)(1-e^{-ix})$.

Comment: Thankyou, this works but is rather messy any other suggestions to simplify the algebra?

Comment: There's no way to not make it messy, I don't think. It's a messy problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use
$$\cos (z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$